# How to setup automatic proxy configuration via pac file windows server core r2

Tags: proxy, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-core

I'm looking for the syntax to setup windows server core R2 to take its proxy configuration from a script(.pac file)

for example in my LAN settings dialog:

Automatic configuration
 use automatic configuration script(checked)
      address http://foo.bar/proxy.pac (text box)

any thoughts on how I can set this netsh doesn't appear to support this unless I'm missing something.

Comment: I noodled around with this for a bit, but I can't see a way, either. I tried to set it in IE (on a non-SC box) and then ran "netsh winhttp import proxy ie" but it had no effect.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply export registry based on this article:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/819961/EN-US

Here is simple script

```
REGEDIT /e c:\proxysetup.reg "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings"
```

After that you may remove rest of file content after section

> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet
>   Settings]

Answer (score -1):

netsh winhttp

I'd use netsh winhttp import proxy - this should import from IE and take a PAC hopefully.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731131(WS.10).aspx

Comment: This only works to import settings from IE to the system services proxy used by services like windows update. It will not work for setting the proxy used by Internet Explorer.